# printf doesn't print on the screen

Tags: c

I downloaded this file [ToyVpnServer.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/server/linux/ToyVpnServer.cpp) and executed the instructions in the file header. then i complied it with `gcc ToyVpnServer.cpp` and then it created a.out, and i ran it (as said in the file header) `./a.out tun0 8000 test -m 1400 -a 10.0.0.2 32 -d 8.8.8.8 -r 0.0.0.0 0`.before i compiled it, as below, i added one line `printf("%d",1000);` in the beginning of the main function which the means it should print `1000` on the screen as soon as executed. but nothing shows and the program keeps running. only when the count of parameters is less than 5, the `printf` function under `if (argc < 5)` works!

I test it on both Ubuntu14 and 16. 
 
what's wrong with it?

```
...
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("%d",1000);
if (argc < 5) {
    printf("Usage: %s <tunN> <port> <secret> options...\n"
           "\n"
           "Options:\n"
           "  -m <MTU> for the maximum transmission unit\n"
           "  -a <address> <prefix-length> for the private address\n"
           "  -r <address> <prefix-length> for the forwarding route\n"
           "  -d <address> for the domain name server\n"
           "  -s <domain> for the search domain\n"
           "\n"
           "Note that TUN interface needs to be configured properly\n"
           "BEFORE running this program. For more information, please\n"
           "read the comments in the source code.\n\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}

// Parse the arguments and set the parameters.
char parameters[1024];
build_parameters(parameters, sizeof(parameters), argc, argv);

...
```

Comment: _it should print 1000 on the screen as soon as executed.?_ `printf("%d",1000);` --> `printf("%d\n",1000);`. Its better to flush the `stdout` buffer by `\n` or `fflush(stdout)` everytime.

Comment: @Achal, can you make your comment as an answer? So AMIR can accept it? (Flushing does print)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it should print 1000 on the screen as soon as executed.?

**No**, `printf()` is a library function and its job is to put the data into `stdout` buffer not directly on console and `stdout` stream is *line buffered* i.e it will display its content only once it reaches the new line.

Here

```
printf("%d",1000);
```

`printf()` doesn't clear/flush the `stdout` stream default, programmer need to do. One way to solve this is use `fflush(stdout)` like

```
printf("%d",1000);
fflush(stdout);
```

or use new line character like

```
printf("%d\n",1000); /* new line character clears the stdout buffer here */
```